# Parse Log In <Use of unresolved identifier 'PFLogInFieldsUsernameAndPassword'>

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I've been having one huge issue that is tying up my entire app because it keeps killing my builds. My bridging header is below:

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <ParseUI/ParseUI.h>
#import <Bolts/Bolts.h>
```

Frameworks have all been downloaded properly. In my View Controller I initially tried:

```
self.logInViewController.fields = 
PFLogInFieldsUsernameAndPassword.value | PFLogInFieldsLogInButton.value |
PFLogInFieldsSignUpButton.value | PFLogInFieldsPasswordForgotten.value |
PFLogInFieldsDismissButton.value
```

to create a custom login page. However, I was met with the error Use of unresolved identifier 'all fields'. I even tried:

```
logInViewController.fields = PFLogInFields( 
PFLogInFieldsUsernameAndPassword.value | 
PFLogInFieldsLogInButton.value | 
PFLogInFieldsSignUpButton.value | 
PFLogInFieldsFacebook.value | PFLogInFieldsTwitter.value 
| PFLogInFieldsPasswordForgotten.value )
```

per the advice of https://www.parse.com/questions/parse-swift-error-with-login-view-controller-fields but that also didn't work.

Please help.

Thanks,

Maxwell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
    PFLogInFields.UsernameAndPassword |
    PFLogInFields.LogInButton |
    PFLogInFields.SignUpButton |
    PFLogInFields.Facebook |
    PFLogInFields.Twitter |
    PFLogInFields.PasswordForgotten
```

When the `PFLogInFields` enumerated type is imported for use with Swift, the "PFLogInFields" prefix of all the enumerated values is stripped off, so "PFLogInFieldsUsernameAndPassword" becomes "UsernameAndPassword", "PFLogInFieldsLogInButton" becomes "LogInButton", etc.  To access the enumerated values of an enumerated type, you use the syntax

```
<Enumerated type>.<Enumerated value>
```